# cement countertop polyurethane tacky in spots

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters

We had cement countertops installed a week ago.  The contractor applied a thick layer of polyurethane (not sure the brand, but he mixed 2 parts of something) within a day or so, most of the poly was dry and smooth.  There are spots that are still very tacky though.  Is this normal?  And how long do I need to wait for it to dry or cure, whatever the term may be?

Comment: It sounds like the parts were not mixed in accurate proportions, or were not mixed well, or perhaps it was old product.  If there are still tacky spots after this many days, it is not likely to cure properly, and there isn't a good, reliable solution to curing what's there.  Have the contractor sand it off and re-apply it.

Comment: Can he just sand the spots and will the reapplication adhear to what is there already?

Comment: Unfortunately, that would be very visible.  The only way to get it to look right is to do the whole surface.

Comment: Are you telling me he'll have to take the whole top, cement and all, off and start over with it?

Comment: It might be possible to do it in place.  It really needs to be assessed in person.  The problem is that there isn't a good way to make the finish cure throughout at this point.  It might be possible to treat the surface so that it isn't tacky, but it will be soft below the surface and won't hold up.

Comment: I'm bummed.   I'll give it more time and see what happens.   Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Linda Stitt I am curious how that ended up turning out, this 6 months later?

Comment: 2 parts means it was probably an epoxy, but yes, it sounds ads though it was not properly mixed or it was a bad batch, and I agree with the other assessments, patching it will be noticeable. It would need to be completely refinished.

Comment: Fixer make your comments an answer and I will up vote, fully agree with them.